# What is the purpose of adding a negation operator in the while condition?

Tags: javascript

can i use the check to find out if yourName variable is false, instead of using the negation operator to change its type.

```js
let yourName;

do {
  yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
}
while (!yourName);

console.log(yourName);
```

the results are the same

Comment: Not really. `prompt` returns either `null` or a string. An `if` with `!` tests for [flasy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the past 5 years of professional enterprise work I've never once seen a `do..while` loop simply because `while()` works just fine I understand in certain scenario's you'd want at least 1 loop but in those cases look to see how you're triggering this function. I can only see a small snippet of it but I wouldn't recommend using this.

JavaScript has a fun time with `if`, `while` when applying the negation operator.

There's plenty of information on this topic, typically I like to reference MDN for new devs to JavaScript as Mozilla has great tutorials  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy.

If `yourName` is of type `undefined` or `null` or `false` or `""` it'll be fine but be careful as there's times when you want to check if `0` value is true. It will return false since it's interpreted 0 as false, example you want to check if value does equal zero `if(0)` will return false. But `if(yourName == 0)`  and `yourName` is 0 it'll return true.

There's a fun bit with double vs triple equality comparisons in JavaScript as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

**What is the purpose of adding a negation operator in the while condition**

> To make sure the value is not an empty string `""`, `undefined`, or `null`.

**Can i use the check to find out if `yourName` variable is false, instead of using the negation operator to change its type**

yes you can check to see if `yourName` is false and it'll work fine without negation it's just a shortcut.

I don't understand what you mean by change its type?

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining the purpose of the negation (!) in the while statement, we must back up and understand `while` loops.

`while` will continue to loop (repeatedly run the code within the brackets) when the condition evaluates to true.

```
while(true){
    // this will run forever
}
```

When the condition evaluates to false the looping stop.

```
while(false) {
    // this will never run
}
```

We can use a variable for a boolean evaluation based on "truthyness".

**Truthyness:**  A funky thing in javascript where boolean evaluations can recognize nil things like `0, null, undefined, ""` as "false", and existing things like `1, "something", object, array` -- anything that "is" or has a value as "true".

```
var bob = true;
while(bob) {
    // this will run one time.
    bob = false;
}
```

You can flip things around using the ! operator:

```
var bob = false; // <-- this is opposite of above
while( ! bob ) { // <-- so we'll use the ! to flip it
    // this will run one time.
    bob = true;
}
```

So the tricky part is that the "negation" operator leverages the funky "truthiness" understanding in the language... we can leverage this and "flip" truthiness entities like string, array, object to check if they "are" or "are not".

So based on our understanding of "truthyness" we can say:

```
var bob = "silly";
bob == true;    // true
!bob == false;  // true

var sally = 0;
sally == false; // true
!sally == true; // true
```

NOTE: Strict type evaluation is handled through triple equals === and !==

Now to the point (let's make things simpler):

```
let yourName;

while ( ! yourName ) {
  // "prompt" will 
  // 1. Block all javascript execution, including this while loop.
  // 2. Return null (falsy) or a text string (truthy)
  yourName = prompt("Who are you?"); 
}
```

So in the above, we are preventing the script from execution until the prompt returns a valid name.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose is to execute a statement while Boolean expression evaluates to false

!false === true

Comment: No. `yourName` is not a boolean expression.

Comment: Yes it is! (yourName) is a boolean expression if it is preceded with if or while keywords!